# Using a 4k monitor with 2 HDMI and a full hd monitor with one hdmi does not show image on the second

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop, external-display, 4k-resolution

I've got a 4k monitor (36") which needs 2 HDMI inputs and a full hd monitor which needs one.

I'm using a usb c dongle for both 4k monitor outputs and a usb to hdmi adapter for the full hd one.

For a few seconds the second monitor (full hd) showed an image but after it it's just black with a message:

```
Not Optimum Mode
Recommended Mode
1920x1080 60Hx
```

The monitor is in windows exactly configured like the message says, even if I change to "wrong" values, nothing happens.

The monitor is in windows detected and I can move windows on it, the problem is, it's just black.
Does anybody know how I can "unblack" my third monitor?

My setup is a Lenovo Yoga 6 with

- Ryzen 7 4700U
- 16 GB RAM
- AMD Radeon Graphics
- Windows 10
- USB to HDMI driver software is called `XXX USB Display`

Comment: It only supports 2 external displays - https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Yoga/Yoga_6_13ALC6/Yoga_6_13ALC6_Spec.html

Comment: @Tetsujin but I'm using two monitors, but I'm just using two cables for one and it worked for a short time

Comment: I'd concentrate on why one display needs two cables & why not just one like everything else. If the system is seeing it as 2 displays side by side, that's your two used up.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm using two cables, because otherwise it would not be detected as a 4k monitor and maximum as fullhd.
At the size of 36" it's impossible to work with such a downscaled resolution.

Comment: Tetsuijn is right. The 4K monitor counts as 2 monitors when connected by 2 cables. Besides that: at 4K resolution you are maxing out the USB-C/DP1.4 bandwidth the Yoga can deliver anyway. A Yoga is simply not designed for this kind of usage.

Comment: @Tonny ok thanks for the explanation, I thought that it should go with an additional usb to hdmi adapter on a laptop usb port. Can't wait to get that new laptop.